# "Jumping" to the Numbers on a keyboard?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a text field where you usually type in numbers. But, the user has to click the numbers button on the keyboard to get to the numbers screen. Is there a way to jump right to the screen on a keyboard with the numbers are available to type?

Any input and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: Can you post an answer of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the keyboard type to one that is only numbers, ie. Number pad or decimal pad. It's an attribute in UITextField's Attribute Inspector in Interface Builder.
[image]